# emacs with SML: how to set folder so emacs console can read file

Tags: emacs, sml

I'm using emacs with SML plugin. I type `C-c C-s` to move to sml console. After that, I want to read file `A.sml` for import purpose.

```
use "A.sml";
```

but I will notice error:

> [use failed: Io: openIn failed on "Pair.sml", Win32TextPrimIO:openRd:
>   failed]

I know this error because emacs doesn't know where to read this file. so, how we set directory or something else like that, so SML console can read this file. (can assume `A.sml` is stored `D:\SML`  )

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do that is to load the file directly into the SML console with `C-c C-l` and skip the intermediate step of switching to SML console followed by `use "A.sml"`. Loading with `C-c C-l` from `A.sml` will show something like this:

```
Load ML file: (default file.sml) ~/Directory/
```

Then press enter to load `file.sml` into the SML console.

Answer (score 0):

In a buffer running sml-mode, you can use `C-c C-b` to interpret its content.

If there doesn't exist an buffer with an SML interpret running, it will ask you which one to start, then interpret the content.
If there already exists such a buffer, it will just interpret the content without any hassle.